# One path/shape SVG with mysterious left padding/white space. Not artboard.

Tags: css, svg

I designed a shape in Illustrator and trimmed artboard to shape so no outside white space. I've done this twice to be sure.

When I open it in Chrome and inspect. If I hover over the whole SVG tag it's tight to the shape. If I hover over the path, there's a white space/padding left (and top, actually) - see screenshot.

It means when I place or animate the shape it's not right. I don't know how I can get rid of it - any ideas?

Code:

```
<div style="margin:100px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 157.144 210.706">
        <path fill="#444" d="M78.394 210.706c-11.247-13.16-22.162-25.304-32.368-38.017-16.016-19.95-30.158-41.092-39.98-64.948-19.25-46.76 9.943-94.135 52.535-105.196 45.651-11.856 91.876 19.016 97.966 65.671 2.028 15.534-1.288 29.968-7.385 44.017-11.15 25.692-27.51 48.023-45.258 69.398-7.965 9.593-16.436 18.766-25.51 29.075zm52.722-131.714c.046-29.268-23.232-52.857-52.283-52.982-28.984-.125-52.775 23.526-52.815 52.506-.041 29.231 23.339 52.858 52.341 52.895 29.291.038 52.712-23.233 52.757-52.419z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no mysterious padding for me. Look https://jsfiddle.net/h729n8ps/

Comment: @mr.boris If you use Chrome, press F12 and highlight the `path` element inside the `svg` element. This reveals some padding. If you highlight the `svg` element, no padding is shown.

Comment: @mr.boris it's as Lars Kristensen says. It's not actually affecting my positioning or animation after all, it was something else. But I'm still confused where this space is coming from, or how to get rid of it. If you paste it into https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor and click 'Edit (Experimental) it shows the red border to illustrate further.

Comment: Sorry, I see now with Chrome. I tried to edit your svg code in Adobe Illustrator and resave it, but this mysterious padding does not go away. It seems that svg code is "broken" or may be it is an Illustrator bug. Try to take some similar icon from [here](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/location-pointer_3913#term=position&page=1&position=13). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/b76zz74d/) is an example without any weird padding

Answer (score 0):

It seems Chrome is taking into account the control points when painting the bounding box:

[image]

You can avoid this by reordering your control points, and this creates a better shape for your pin:

[image]

Here's the Path, but I did it quickly, you might want to redraw it yourself with more care.

```
 <path d="m78.394,211.00938c-11.247,-13.16 -22.162,-25.304 -32.368,-38.017c-16.016,-19.95 -44.72017,-56.5643 -45.74419,-94.98246c-1.02402,-38.41816 32.67117,-77.86771 78.32217,-77.89195c45.651,-0.02424 78.27532,41.16539 78.54978,79.92979c0.27446,38.7644 -35.50176,80.51162 -53.24976,101.88662c-7.965,9.593 -16.436,18.766 -25.51,29.075zm52.722,-131.714c0.046,-29.268 -23.232,-52.857 -52.283,-52.982c-28.984,-0.125 -52.775,23.526 -52.815,52.506c-0.041,29.231 23.339,52.858 52.341,52.895c29.291,0.038 52.712,-23.233 52.757,-52.419z" fill="#444"/>
```